# Can't display x and y labels, when plotting with the quantreg command

Tags: r, plot, quantreg

I'm trying to plot the result of the quantreg command, but the labels of the graph don't show up. I'm running this code:

```
plot(summary(qrg), parm="agua_esgoto", xlab = "Quantiles", ylab = "Piped water and sewage", main = "Figure 1")
```

This is the image that was returned:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margins need to be set in order to see the y or x labels, you can check out the options under [the vignette](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantreg/versions/5.51/topics/plot.rqss)

For example:

```
data("engel")
fm <- rq(foodexp ~ income, data = engel, tau = 1:9/10)

plot(fm,parm=2)
# no x or y labels can be seen
```

[image]

```
plot(fm, parm = 2, mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1), 
main = "", xlab = "tau", ylab = "income coefficient")
```

[image]